# LabVIEW case structure and PWM

Tags: arduino, labview, pwm

I am facing a trouble with LabVIEW; I am working on this simple program which is a part of a bigger school project. For some reason, a part of it isn't being executed properly. Simply put, a green LED should turn on when the temperature is below 20, whilst a red LED should turn on when it is over 30 (It works until this part), now the tricky part is, a fan should turn on when the temperature is over 35, while using PWM to increase the fan speed as long as the temperature is rising. The thing is, the fan doesn't turn on whatsoever! I used Scaling and Mapping inside a case structure for that, I have set it to 0 when the temperature is 35, and 255 when it is 45 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're having problems with code, you're more likely to get an answer if you could show what you have so far, what doesn't work and how, and what you've tried. If the problem isn't with code but with circuitry, you should post it at the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange site: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello I'm not familiar with the Andruino functions for the I/O that you are using. Are you sure you're generating a PWM , is it possible that you keep writing in the same value in each iteration of your loop to the I/O meaning your signal doesn't vary?

Comment: Have you tried starting from the beginning with the fan control: write some code that only sets up the PWM output to a level you specify, without a loop? Does that work? If so then add the other functions in until you find where it stops working. Instead of letting the waveform output of 'Scaling and Mapping' get coerced to a number at the input of the Arduino VI (shown by a red dot) try explicitly converting it to a DBL and check the value coming out is what it should be. Also perhaps move the output configuration VI's outside the loop - you should only need to configure them once.

Answer (score 2):

**Things you may want to change:**

1. Put the `Set Digital Pin Mode.vi` in front of the while loop because you are not changing the pin mode during the execution of the code
2. You need only one `Close.vi` since you are closing only one `Arduino Resource`
3. Use `shift registers` to preserve the content the error wire between iterations of the loop
4. If possible avoid `Express VIs` (VIs with this blue frame)

**An example for PWM (tested with a Mega 2560):**

I think the reason why my version works and yours does not is that there is something wrong with the scaling. I have not used `Scaling and Mapping` instead I have scaled the signal with basic math operations.

[image: Front panel]
[image: Block diagram]

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with Express VI's as a general rule, you just need to understand what it is they're doing - same as for any other function. In this case I think you're right that the OP needs to check whether the output of `Scaling and Mapping` is actually giving them the value they want after coercion.